# Adding Variable into a file path variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, salt-stack

I am taking below input:

```py
id = input("Enter the minion name you want to connect : Ex: HK_5871_f - ")
```

Now I want the input provided by user as `HK_5871_f` :

```py
path="/var/cache/salt/master/minions/$id"
print (path)
```

The output should be as below:

```
/var/cache/salt/master/minions/HK_5871_f
```

But I am getting the below output:

```
/var/cache/salt/master/minions/$id
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python 3.6+ you can use f-string formatting

An Example:

```
id =  "HK_5871_f"
path = f'/var/cache/salt/master/minions/{id}'
print(path)
```

Output:

```
/var/cache/salt/master/minions/HK_5871_f
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the assignment of `id` as text instead of its value `HK_5871_f`.

You should set `path` variable somewhat like below:

```py
path = "/var/cache/salt/master/minions/%s" % id
print(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done with the "+" operator since it is a string. This operation is called concatenation.

The code below should work fine:

```
id = input("Enter the minion name you want to connect : Ex: HK_5871_f - ")
path = "/var/cache/salt/master/minions/"+id
```

Output:

```
/var/cache/salt/master/minions/HK_5871_f
```